# Testing real visibility with jquery - :visible gives wrong results

Tags: jquery, css, visibility

Is this possible to detect true visibility of element when the parent has scroll and obscures it?

This didn't work with `:visible`: http://jsbin.com/kalesuqu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: is(':visible') works only if the element has set **visibility: hidden;** or **display: none;**. You must check the overflowed viewport of your DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) plugin, and use the `:below-the-fold` attribute to find out whether the element exists on the page but is currently not in view:

```
$(":below-the-fold")
```

Then, if you were to use, say:

```
var vis = $("#chat").children(":first").is(":below-the-fold");
var notVis = $("#chat").children(":last").is(":below-the-fold");
```

`vis` would return `false` as it is currently visible, and `notVis` would return `true` as it is "below the fold".

This diagram should help explain things in regard to what the selectors that come with VSFjQuery mean:

[image]

<kbd>[**Here is a demo of it in use.**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but *below-the-fold* is not what I am looking for. The element could be above the fold, yet not visible (be under the bottom edge of `chat`).

Comment: @Majid Then you could just use :above-the-top? You should check out the demo, I believe it works for most cases when using a combination of the selectors.